# @Html.Actionlink que en href envie el #seccion

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hola a todos estoy realizando una página con secciones en MVC y quiero ver si es posible generar un link como el siguiente:

<a class="d-flex" href="~/Home/Index **#Portafolio**"

Nótese que el parámetro que quiero agregar es el que está en negritas pero desde `@Html.ActionLink("Portafolio" "Index", "Home")` para poder lograr este como lo tendría que realizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `@Url.Action` en lugar de [@Html.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

```
<a class="d-flex" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")#Portafolio">Portafolio</a>
```

Esto solo es necesario si la URL apunta a otra página, ya que si está en la misma página solo debes hacer:

```
<a class="d-flex" href="#Portafolio">Portafolio</a>
```

Comment: Tal vez quieras agregar algo más a la respuesta. Apareció en la cola de baja calidad.

Comment: @Mateo Gracias por el aviso!